# Unable to start Sidekiq on my local machine: Error connecting to Redis on redis:6379 (SocketError)

Tags: redis, configuration, sidekiq

I have Redis running from a Rails app but when I try to start Sidekiq (bundle exec sidekiq), I am getting

```
INFO: Booting Sidekiq 6.0.4 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redis:6379/0", :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-49487"}
Error connecting to Redis on redis:6379 (SocketError)
```

I looked at my redis.conf file and I'm sure I haven't changed any of the defaults. What else could I check for?

sidekiq (6.0.4)
rails (6.0.2.1)
redis (4.1.3)

Answer (score 9):

Turns out I was using the wrong Redis address in my Rails .env file as it was configured for Docker. Sidekiq was unable to find the right Redis port.

Changed from `redis://redis:6379/0` to `redis:6379/0`.

Comment: What was the right address? I have a similar address. What change did you make? Please be explicit. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DianaE. Sorry, I haven't logged in here for ages and just saw your message. I changed it from redis://redis:6379/0 to redis:6379/0

Answer (score 3):

The `redis` hostname doesn't exist (use `localhost`?) or you haven't started Redis.